# On Circuitpython, how to decompress files from tar or gzip file?

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

I can use utarfile.py to untar a file on Micropython.

But for circuitpython, even the latest 8.0.0 beta2.
There is no circuitpython version of utar, gzip library, or something like that.
If I use the uarfile.py, there is also no uctypes modules on circuitpython.

Could anybody tell me how to decompress a tar or gzip file on Circuitpython.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm on the same boat, did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and thought of taking a look at tarfile in the MicroPython std-lib.

As noted in the question uCtypes aren't supported in CircuitPython which means I had to replace those instances in the code with the standard python-struct which is supported in CircuitPython.

This version that I created should be fully portable to any Python3 and above and thus provides a way of unarchiving an uncompressed tar-archive without any external dependencies.

I have published the pure implementation on github at:
https://github.com/rickyosser/tarfile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).